# Как реализуются службы, которые срабатывают по расписанию?

Tags: c#, .net, service

Предположим, нужно сделать службу, которая должна выполнять разного вида задачи по некоторому расписанию, которое задается в конфигурации(Например, список времен и типов задач).

Как это правильно делается?

Правильно ли создавать список таймеров, на каждый таймер привязывать обработчик события(В зависимости от типа задачи), затем высчитывать время срабатывания в мс относительно текущего времени, а потом запускать отсчет?

Нашел еще какой-то Quartz.NET... На сколько он хорош?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quartz.NET не пробовал, попробуйте, вдруг понравится =)

Обычно "Правильно" у каждого свое, мои соображения следующие:

**1. Короткие интервалы (секунды, минуты)**

Набор задач для коротких интервалов времени обычно фиксирован и задачи тесно связаны между собой. Поэтому предложенный вами вариант будет вполне уместным, но есть и недостатки: При перезапуске службы все задачи будут прерваны в произвольном месте, если не предусмотрен особый код завершения работы службы, таймеры будут перезапущены. Для изменения интервалов необходимо перезапускать службу, если не предусмотрена специальная команда для этого.

К достоинствам можно отнести возможность прямой передачи данных между задачами  с использованием привычных типов данных, достаточно высокую точность срабатывани по времени, для ультра коротких интервалов можно использовать таймер на основе `StopWatch`, имеющий максимальную точность измерения времени.

Альтернативой может служить набор консольных программ (одна задача - одна программа) запускаемых с помощью системного планировщика. Для коротких интервалов преимущества данного метода весьма сомнительны если вообще есть.

**2. Средние интервалы (часы, дни)**

Набор задач для таких интервалов иногда требует изменений набора выполняемых действий, а также принудительного выполнения задач мне расписания, что также накладывает ряд требований на применяемое решение.

В службе с внутренними таймерами, придется предусмотреть специальные методы для управления списком выполняемых задач, принудительного запуска отдельных задач, сохранения расписания не смотря на внеплановый запуск. Также стоит отметь что служба будет висеть в памяти постоянно и расходовать ресурсы, особенно печально если где-то есть незначительная утечка, которую сразу не выявили.

Для набора программ работающих по системному планировщику, ничего дополнительного делать не придется, этот функционал уже заложен в системном планировщике. Системный планировщик задач в любом случае запущен всегда, а вот ваши задачи будут потреблять ресурсы только во время выполнения, проблема постоянной утечки памяти при длительной работе отсутствует. Добавление и удаление задач не составляет особого труда. Возможно обновление программ выполняющих задачи независимо друг от друга. Возможно увеличение производительности за счет запуска особо тяжелых задач на отдельных компьютерах. К недостаткам - необходимость обмена данными между связанными задачами посредством файлов. Учитывая длину интервалов файловый обмен не очень страшен, но время на разработку протокола и формата файлов потратить придется.

**3. Длинные интервалы (недели, месяцы, годы)**

Набор задач почти гарантированно будет меняться в процессе работы, и задачи редко бывают связаны между собой, либо объединяются в одну большую задачу. Со мной могут не согласиться другие участники, но лично мне, на таких интервалах использовать монолитную службу просто неудобно. К тому же в службе придется предусмотреть еще и синхронизацию времени, хотя бы с системными часами, и календарем, если нужно запускать задание, например раз в неделю, или по первым числам месяцев. Системный планировщик в данном случае освобождает разработчика от необходимости писать что либо кроме кода выполняемых задач.

**4. Неопределенные интервалы или работа по событию**

Этот вариант конечно имеет малое отношение к таймерам, однако в рамках сравнения двух подходов его стоит рассмотреть.

В службе необходимо предусмотреть код слушающий необходимые события. Обрабатываемые события могут быть вынесены в конфигурацию, а вот добавление или удаление действий без пересборки и переустановки службы уже не сделать.

Системный планировщик также умеет срабатывать по событиям, но ограничен событиями, которые отслеживает операционная система. Чтобы добавить что-то свое, придется определить и зарегистрировать в системном логе источник событий, коды событий, возможно даже отдельный журнал событий и т.д. В отдельных сложных случаях результат стоит потраченного времени. Также для сложных случаев обработки событий можно написать свой планировщик, который будет реагировать на все что вам нужно и запускать программы для обработки задач вместо системного планировщика.

В целом, для работы по событиям, можно считать оба способа равнозначными.

**Собственный планировщик задач.**

В некоторых случаях использовать системный планировщик не очень удобно. Тогда можно реализовать свой. Идея довольно простая:

- один таймер с фиксированным минимальным шагом, например раз в секунду.
- по событию таймера сравниваем текущее время с расписанием запланированных заданий.
- запускаем в отдельном потоке или процессе выполнение заданий, время которых меньше либо равно текущему.

Answer (score 2):

Для простых случаев -- запускать задачу раз в N секунд/минут/часов, один инстанс сервиса, нет критичных требований к запускам -- таймеров будет достаточно.

Если же вам нужны гибкие расписания (читай, cron expressions), фейловер, возможность ребалансировки, персистентность, тогда лучше использовать Quartz.NET.

Comment: А тот же Quartz.NET внутри реализовывается на таймерах?

Comment: @iluxa1810 понятия не имею. Почитайте [исходники](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet).