# Как запустить метод раз в сутки?

Tags: c#, таймер, schedule

Как сделать чтобы метод `Run` выполнялся всё время,а метод `Run2` раз в сутки. И когда `Run2` работает - `Run` ждёт.

```
private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var date = DateTime.Now;

    if (date.Hour >= 3 && date.Hour < 4 && date.Minute < 10)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        Run2();
        Thread.Sleep(600000); // пауза 10 минут
        timer.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: `чтобы метод Run выполнялся всё время` бесконечный цикл

Comment: `метод Run2 раз в сутки` таймер

Comment: `И когда Run2 работает - Run ждёт` см [lock statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Делаешь 2 таски

```
Task Run;
Task RunOncePerDay; //(в конце этой таски анпаузишь Run)

DateTime RunOncePerDayTimeOfRun;
```

Используешь Timer. Размер таймера ставишь в 1000; В таймер тик засовываешь код вроде:

```
if (RunOncePerDayTimeOfRun >= DateTime.Now && < DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1))
{
   Run.Pause();
   RunOncePerDay.Run();
} 

if(RunOncePerDay.Status != TaskStatus.Runned && Run.Status = TaskStatus.Finished)
{
    Run.Start();
}
```

Уверен что в коде я налажал с использованием синтаксиса т.к. писал от понта не помня нифига. Но исправив ошибки синтаксиса и оставив даную логику -- код должен работать.

---

Так же можно использовать внешние библиотеки заточенные под эти нужды. Кажется была какая-то библиотека вроде Cron или Quartz или как-то так. Возможно использовать внешний нюгет будет проще и лучше.

Comment: [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), при наличии длительных интервалов, лучше. А если есть возможность вынести код, который должен исполняться раз в сутки/неделю/месяц/год в отдельный исполняемый модуль то еще лучше - запуск модуля настраивается в системном планировщике. Длинные интервалы вообще отдельная тема. [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/568157/198316) уже писал, но немного устарело, успел оценить кварц в качестве кастомного планировщика, понравилось.